# How do I configure Ubuntu Server to access a WPA2 Enterprise WiFi Access Point?

Tags: wireless, server, 13.10, wpa2

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 server and would like to be able to access the WiFi in my university [using these setting](http://www.depts.ttu.edu/ithelpcentral/solutions/wireless/). I have searched through numerous posts and found several configurations, none of which work. How do I get get this connection to work?

Can this be done without without SU privileges? How do I extend this for multiple SSIDs - for home (WPA2-personal) and the University (WPA2 Enterprise) ?

```
Network Name or SSID (case-sensitive):  TTUnet
Network Security or Authentication:  WPA2 Enterprise
Data Encryption:  AES
EAP Type:  PEAP/MS-CHAP-V2
When prompted for user credentials, use the following:

User Name:  your eRaider username
Password:  your eRaider password
Domain:  TTU
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will end up with multiple wireless profiles; one for home and one (or more) for the Uni.

You do not need *sudo su* to do this. The wpa-supplicant app that's standard with Ubuntu and lets you connect to any available wireless network in range.

> wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -B -c /path/to/wpa_supplicant.conf

Switch out the wpa_supplicant.conf files based on whether you are at home or the Uni.

http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap.git;a=blob_plain;f=wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf illustrates the configuration file options.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a list to select from. I am at the console and do not have a GUI. All I can do is edit files with nano. How do I configure my computer to access a WPA2 enterprise access point from the shell?

Comment: Due to too much trouble I ditched the installation all together. The answer is only accepted to improve my acceptance ratio.

Comment: I think that K7AAY meant that you swap by pointing wpa_supplicant to another config file.